# Why isnt my logistic regression model output a factor of 2 levels? (Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.)

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, r-caret

From reading similar questions I know that the problem is that the `yhat.logisticReg` isnt a factor of 2 levels while `training.prepped$TARGET_FLAG` is.  I assume the issue could be fixed by changing my model or in the prediction so that `yhat.logisticReg` is a factor of 2 levels. How can I do this?

```
logisticReg = glm(TARGET_FLAG ~ .,
                  data = training.prepped,
                  family = binomial())
yhat.logisticReg = predict(logisticReg, training.prepped, type = "response")
confusionMatrix(yhat.logisticReg, training.prepped$TARGET_FLAG)

Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

```
str(training.prepped$TARGET_FLAG)
Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...

str(yhat.logisticReg)
 Named num [1:8161] 0.1656 0.2792 0.3717 0.0894 0.272 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8161] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Comment: Hey Jacob, you are trying to compare a factor with a numeric value. You need to transform your `yhat.logisticReg` to binary.

Comment: I figured it was something along those lines. How would you suggest I do that? Could I simply do a list comprehension if/else statement after the `predict` line or is there a better option? @Filipe Lauaur

Comment: Which metric do you want to optimize? I have a code in R that find the best threshold to your problem. It’s better then just an if/else.

Comment: I need to predict "crash" or "no crash".  Where `1` represents a crash and `0` represents no crash.  I'm not entirely sure which metric would be the most practical to optimize for but I assume "accuracy" as reported by the `confusionMatrix` function would be a good choice @Filipe Lauar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to choose a threshold first, and then convert your real-valued data into binary values, e.g.

```
a <- c(0.2, 0.7, 0.4)
threshold <- 0.5
binary_a <- factor(as.numeric(a>threshold))

str(binary_a)
Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1
```

Comment: This (with the edits I made) solved my issue, though Filipe is correct that 0.5 may not be the threshold that gives the most accuracy.  

`binary_a <- factor(a>threshold)` also works and the levels would be "TRUE" and "FALSE" which may be more appropriate, but as it is written it matches my `TARGET_FLAG` variable.

Comment: Or better yet choose the threshold that maximizes AUC or kappa on the test set.

Answer (score 0):

The library caret have the method `confusionMatrix` that have several metrics implemented. Calling `overall` you can get the accuracy. If you want another metric, you can check if they have it implemented and just call it.

```
library(caret)
acc = c()
for(value in yhat.logisticReg)
{
  predictions <- ifelse(yhat.logisticReg <= value, 0, 1)
  confusion_matrix = confusionMatrix(predictions, yhat.logisticReg)
  acc = c(acc,confusion_matrix$overall["Accuracy"])
}

best_acc = max(acc)
best_threshold  = yhat.logisticReg[which.max(acc)]
```

Comment: I get the error `Error in accuracy(predictions, yhat.logisticReg) : 
  could not find function "accuracy"`

Comment: As I said, the function accuracy is present in some packages, I will update the answer with a code that works.

Comment: when I call `best_acc`  I get the result `1075.698` and when I call `best_threshold` it returns `<NA> 
  NA `.  This seems like an error.

Comment: Sorry Jacob, that quantile was a mistake. I updated the code, I think now it works.